# webscraping and saving the result as json

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to scrape the website with beautifulsoup in this way:

1. From home page the 40 categories Just names
2. Then go to every category e.g (startupstash.com/ideageneration/) and in that there will be some sub categories
3. Now go to every subcategory suppose first one startupstash.com/resource/milanote/ and take the content details

4 .This same way to all the 40 categories+numbers of subcategories+each sub category details.

Please someone can provide me a Idea how to approach..or method with beautifulsoup..or possible code..i tried something down

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}


base_url="http://startupstash.com/"
req_home_page=requests.get(base_url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req_home_page.text, "html5lib")
links_tag=soup.find_all('li', {'class':'categories-menu-item'})
titles_tag=soup.find_all('span',{'class':'name'})
links,titles=[],[]

for link in links_tag:
    links.append(link.a.get('href'))
#print(links)
for title in titles_tag:
    titles.append(title.getText())
print("HOME PAGE TITLES ARE \n",titles)                                                              
#HOME PAGE RESULT TITLE FINISH HERE

for i in range(0,len(links)):
    req_inside_page = requests.get(links[i],headers=headers)
    page_store =BeautifulSoup(req_inside_page.text, "html5lib")
    jump_to_next=page_store.find_all('div', { 'class' : 'company-listing more' })
    nextlinks=[]
    for div in jump_to_next:
        nextlinks.append(div.a.get("href"))
    print("DETAIL OF THE LINKS IN EVERY CATEGORIES SCRAPPED HERE \n",nextlinks)                     #SCRAPPED THE WEBSITES IN EVERY CATEGORIES

    for j in range(0,len(nextlinks)):
        req_final_page=requests.get(nextlinks[j],headers=headers)
        page_stored=BeautifulSoup(req_final_page.text,'html5lib')
        detail_content=page_stored.find('div', { 'class' : 'company-page-body body'})
        details,website=[],[]
        for content in detail_content:
        details.append(content.string)
        print("DESCRIPTION ABOUT THE WEBSITE \n",details)                                       #SCRAPPED THE DETAILS OF WEBSITE 


        detail_website=page_stored.find('div',{'id':"company-page-contact-details"})
        table=detail_website.find('table')
        for tr in table.find_all('tr')[2:]:
            tds=tr.find_all('td')[1:]
            for td in tds:
                website.append(td.a.get('href'))
                print("VISIT THE WEBSITE \n",website)
```

Comment: What exact problems do you have? Please describe what you tried and couldn't achieve. Nobody is going to write the whole scraper for you.

Comment: @ VeGABAU  ..I need just the approach to solve this whole website..from the first page I need all the categories names,second go to each categories and third take  the detail section  from the third page.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , first you need to add 'User-Agent' in your headers to simulate a web browser ( please don't abuse the website ) .
Then you can extract the links from the first page with this line :

```
links = [ li.a.get('href') for li in soup.find_all('li', {'class':'categories-menu-item'}) ]
```

Then loop over those links and get the links for each of them :

```
links = [ div.a.get('href') for div in soup.find_all('div', { 'class' : 'company-listing-more' }) ]
```

Finally get the content :

```
content = soup.find('div', { 'class' : 'company-page-body body'}).text
```

Comment: It wasn't that hard, all you have to do is inspect the html and select the appropriate tags

Comment: @adam, I tried many more ways ,result is not getting executed.I have changed the code above,if possible check once and let me know the mistake for the home page execution.Result is coming just finished in x sec...

Comment: Please read my post carefully . a)  you need to set 'User-Agent' in the headers , eg `headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}` ,  b)  for every link you get you need to send a new get request , c) your second for loop should be inside the first for loop . If you do this correctly , you should end up with 400 links . Try to implement those points in your code and let me know how it works out

Comment: Dear @adam, how wonderful person you are..you are bravo..take my respect ..for your 3 lines code idea it is written by this 30 days python learner  and  it is wonderfully working (you can check there,I editied)..But results are all in list..Now I have to check to make it to JSON and save to mongodb..

Comment: Your code looks quite ok to me up to this point . You can find may posts on this site about list -> json to move it forword . I 'm very glad i could point you to the right direction , and resolve this issue . Enjoy coding with python !

Comment: Thank you very much @t.m.adam you are wonderful..You are hero